# How can I echo a variable and redirect it to a file, register or the clipboard?

Tags: command-line, variables

I'm using a colour scheme which makes some text unreadable in the vim terminal. Therefore I want to alter `g:terminal_ansi_colors`.

```
:echo g:terminal_ansi_colors
```

This shows me the value of the variable, but I cannot select the text. What can I do to select the text, or how can I redirect the variable value to a file, a vim register or the system clipboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:

```
:redir @* | echo g:terminal_ansi_colors | redir END
```

It moves the output of `echo g:terminal_ansi_colors` to the `*` register.

Comment: Perfect, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. If the solution fit your need maybe you can accept it. It allow the question to rest ;-)

Comment: Using `setreg()`, `let @* = thevar`, or even `:put=thevar` would have been simpler. Did I miss something?

Comment: For that case it is even better indeed :-)